# How do you mock/test requestjs requestcallback with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, restify, request-promise, requestjs

I am making a get request to an API using requestjs and then in the requestCallBack mapping the body to a custom json object. I am trying to test this code using Jest but no matter how I mock it, it doesn't seem to work

I have tried `request.get.mockImplementation()` and that seems to only mock the get and doesn't let me test the code in the callback

```
    await request.get('endpoint', requestOptions, (err, res, body) => { transformBodyContent(body) })
```

```
    jest.mock('request')
    jest.mock('request-promise-native')

    import request from 'request-promise-native'

    test('test requestCallback code', async () => {
        // not sure how to test that bodyTransformer is called and is working
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the arguments a mock was called with using [`mockFn.mock.calls`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockcalls).

In this case `request.get` is a mock function (since the entire `request-promise-native` was [auto-mocked](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options)), so you can use `request.get.mock.calls` to get the arguments it was called with.  The third argument will be your callback, so you can retrieve it and then test it like this:

```
jest.mock('request-promise-native');

import request from 'request-promise-native';

test('test requestCallback code', () => {
  request.get('endpoint', requestOptions, (err, res, body) => { transformBodyContent(body) });

  const firstCallArgs = request.get.mock.calls[0];  // get the args the mock was called with
  const callback = firstCallArgs[2];  // callback is the third argument

  // test callback here
});
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks Brian. Another question: how would I grab and test a parameter in that callback IE `(req, res, body) => { this.firstName = body.firstName }` When I use your code provided I seem to always get back undefined for body

Comment: Figured it out Brian - just had to pass in the args I needed. Really appreciate the help. Thanks!